# How to create a node with multiple relationship NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

I wondered if someone knew how to create this following graph using Neo4J.

The main issue is when it comes to create two relationship with node called 'John'

Thanks a million in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCZE2.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. To create such graph you can do the following query:

```
create (john:Person {name: 'John'})
create (sara:Person {name: 'Sara'})
create (joe:Person {name: 'Joe'})
create (maria:Person {name: 'Maria'})
create (steve:Person {name: 'Steve'})

merge (john)-[:FRIEND]->(sara)
merge (john)-[:FRIEND]->(joe)
merge (sara)-[:FRIEND]->(maria)
merge (joe)-[:FRIEND]->(steve)
```

What is the issue you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks a million! My issue was that i was trying to create it at once in a single statement:         `CREATE (:Person{name: 'John'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person{name: 'Sara'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person{name: 'Maria'})
CREATE (:Person{name: 'John'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person{name: 'Joe'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person{name: 'Steve'})`

Comment: Ah ok, I got it! Depends on the case, but in general creation of nodes and relationships should be kept separated, otherwise you can incur in some errors or unexpected behaviour. If the my answer solve your doubt, please close this question with the "solved check"